# How can we pass a variable and use it inside a yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I need to perform string interpolation inside yml file, to create a custom error message based on a value which I will pass to locale yml file.

something like

```
users:
  error1: "custom error message based on variable #{passed_in_var}"
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [I18n interpolation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#passing-variables-to-translations)!

```
users:
  error1: "custom error message based on variable %{passed_in_var}"
```

Then you call it like this:

```
t('users.error1', passed_in_var: 'foobar')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use .yml.erb, you can bind variables to ERB. Ref: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html

```
variable1 = "text1"
variable2 = "text2"
ERB.new(template).result(binding)
```

This will use the current block's context to interpolate the variables in the ERB template.